# Boolean on scroll working unexpectedly

Tags: animation, modifiers

[Here is the problem statement](https://developer.blender.org/T75267)

Broken: version: 2.81 (sub 16), branch: master, commit date: 2019-12-04 11:32, hash: rBf1aa4d18d49d

I have array of objects. And i want to give scroll effect. Now when i use cube on it to display only overlapping objects it show only one which come fully under it. Like if i scroll and half box from it go out it will remove whole object. In ideal case it must show half of that object.

Exact steps for others to reproduce the error

1. Create a cube (representing post on the mobile screen)
2. resize it
3. Add array modifer
4. Create new cube
5. overLap it on arrays of cube(post)
6. Select Post array and then add boolean modifer
7. then intersect ( in boolean modifer )
8. It only showing post which come fully inside it
   [image]

[image]
We can see that post is loaded only after it fully enter the Boolean container. And disappear after it fully exit.

It has happened twice. I think it may be caused after adding materials ( i only added colors though ) Any help will be appreciated

---

Here are the modifier object added to post array 
[image]

Comment: try scaling the boolean box a bit on x axis

Comment: @ShantanuAryan Will try in shortly

Comment: @ShantanuAryan But scaling will only cut the box(Ideally ). Here The case is if box did not enter the cutter object fully it wont appear. And when getting out it disappear when fully out (Ideally it should show cutting effect )

Comment: Boolean modifiers do not work properly with overlapping geometries. It seems like the boolean box has a perfect fit along x axis. try scaling it out a little

Comment: @ShantanuAryan I just tried scaling to x-axis but did not get resolved. I think this is bug in Blender